# How to create recipes Python for android

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm a beginner in this and I really need help. I've successfully installed everything you need to convert Kivy code into an Android application. Everything works, but in my code I have used the PyMySQL module that does not exist in Python-for-Android recipes.
For some time I have been unsuccessfully searching the Internet for the solution. I found that non-reciping modules should be installed automatically with the help of pip. But that does not happen.
I installed the PyMySQL module with pip, but the buildozer does not recognize it. When I enter the "pip list" command PyMySQL is in the list of installed modules.
In addition to the above, when executing the "buildozer android debug" command, the module does not connect to the application, it simply skips it.
One of the solutions to this problem is to make a recipe for this module.
My problem is that I'm a beginner and I do not know how to do it.
Please Help. If possible step by step.
I would like to add that the code works on Windows and Linux. Which would mean that there is no problem in the code. Thanks in advance.

```
import pymysql
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


Window.clearcolor = (0.86, 0.84, 0.76, 1)

podaci = []


def provera1(d1, d2, v1, v2, b1, b2):
    """ Check that the numbers are entered and not the text. """
    if d1:
        try:
            int(d1)
        except ValueError:
            return False
    if d2:
        try:
            int(d2)
        except ValueError:
            return False
    if v1:
        try:
            int(v1)
        except ValueError:
            return False
    if v2:
        try:
            int(v2)
        except ValueError:
            return False
    if b1:
        try:
            int(b1)
        except ValueError:
            return False
    if b2:
        try:
            int(b2)
        except ValueError:
            return False
    return True


def kamen_db():
    global podaci
    materijali = []

    for i in podaci:
        kod = str(i[0])
        mat = str(i[1])
        duz = str(i[2])
        vis = str(i[3])
        deb = str(i[4])
        poz = str(i[5])
        materijal = "Kod: "+kod+"\nMaterijal: "+mat+"\nDimenzije: "+duz+"x"+vis+"x"+deb+"\nPozicija: "+poz
        materijali.append(materijal)
        podaci = materijali

    return podaci


def connect_base():
    try:
        # Opening DB connection
        db = pymysql.connect("localhost", "testuser", "test123", "granit_novak")
        db.close()
        a = True
        return a

    except pymysql.err.OperationalError:
        a = False
        return a


def pokusaj_konekcije(p_kod, p_materijal, p_duz1, p_duz2, p_vis1, p_vis2, p_deb1, p_deb2, p_pozicija):
    try:
        # Opening DB connection
        db = pymysql.connect("localhost", "testuser", "test123", "granit_novak")

        # creating cursor()
        cursor = db.cursor()

        # KOD
        if p_kod:
            upit_kod = "'" + p_kod + "'"
        else:
            upit_kod = 'kod'

        # MATERIJAL
        if p_materijal:
            upit_materijal = "'" + p_materijal + "'"
        else:
            upit_materijal = 'kamen.materijali'

        # DUZINA
        v_duz1 = p_duz1 or p_duz2
        v_duz2 = p_duz2 or p_duz1

        if v_duz1 and v_duz2:
            upit_duz = ' BETWEEN ' + str(v_duz1) + ' AND ' + str(v_duz2)
        else:
            upit_duz = '= duzina'

        # VISINA
        v_vis1 = p_vis1 or p_vis2
        v_vis2 = p_vis2 or p_vis1

        if v_vis1 and v_vis2:
            upit_vis = ' BETWEEN ' + str(v_vis1) + ' AND ' + str(v_vis2)
        else:
            upit_vis = '= visina'

        # DEBLJINA
        v_deb1 = p_deb1 or p_deb2
        v_deb2 = p_deb2 or p_deb1

        if v_deb1 and v_deb2:
            upit_deb = ' BETWEEN ' + str(v_deb1) + ' AND ' + str(v_deb2)
        else:
            upit_deb = '= debljina'

        # POZICIJA
        if p_pozicija:
            upit_pozicija = "'" + p_pozicija + "'"
        else:
            upit_pozicija = 'lokacija.pozicije'

        komanda = 'SELECT kod, materijali, duzina, visina, debljina, pozicije\
                            FROM glavna INNER JOIN kamen INNER JOIN lokacija ON glavna.materijal = kamen.rb AND\
                            glavna.pozicija = lokacija.rb'

        upit_where = ' WHERE kod = ' + upit_kod + ' AND kamen.materijali = ' + upit_materijal + '\
                                AND duzina ' + upit_duz + ' AND visina ' + upit_vis + '\
                                AND debljina ' + upit_deb + ' AND pozicije = ' + upit_pozicija + ''

        komanda = komanda + upit_where
        cursor.execute(komanda)
        pretraga = cursor.fetchall()
        db.close()
        return pretraga
    except pymysql.err.OperationalError:
        ScreenOne.konekcija_popup()


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    """ First screen. """

    def konekcija(self, kod_entry, mat_entry, duz_od, duz_do, vis_od, vis_do, deb_od, deb_do, poz_entry):
        izbor = provera1(duz_od, duz_do, vis_od, vis_do, deb_od, deb_do)

        if izbor is True:
            a = connect_base()
            if a is True:
                global podaci
                podaci = pokusaj_konekcije(kod_entry, mat_entry, duz_od, duz_do,
                                           vis_od, vis_do, deb_od, deb_do, poz_entry)

                kamen_db()
                self.change_screen()
                return podaci
            else:
                self.konekcija_popup()

        else:
            self.unos_popup()

    def change_screen(self):
        if self.manager.current == 'Pretraga':
            self.manager.current = 'Tabela'
            Window.clearcolor = (0.38, 0.57, 0.69, 1)
        else:
            self.manager.current = 'Pretraga'

    @staticmethod
    def konekcija_popup():
        popup = Popup(title='Baza',
                      content=Label(text='Konekcija sa bazom\nnije uspostavljena.\n\nPokušajte ponovo.'),
                      size_hint=(.7, .5))
        popup.open()

    @staticmethod
    def unos_popup():
        popup = Popup(title='Unos',
                      content=Label(text='Uneseni podaci nisu\nu ispravnom formatu.\n\nProverite da li ste uneli\n'
                                         'tekst umesto cifara u\npolja sa dimenzijama.'),
                      size_hint=(.7, .5))
        popup.open()


class ScreenTwo(Screen, BoxLayout):
    """ Second screen. """
    global podaci

    def populate(self):
        self.rv.data = [{'value': str(x)} for x in podaci]

    def clear(self):
        self.rv.data = []

    @staticmethod
    def prikaz():
        if podaci:
            print(podaci)
            kamen_db()
        else:
            print("Nema nista.")

    def change_screen(self):
        if self.manager.current == 'Tabela':
            self.manager.current = 'Pretraga'
            Window.clearcolor = (0.86, 0.84, 0.76, 1)
        else:
            self.manager.current = 'Tabela'


class Manager(ScreenManager):

    screen_one = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_two = ObjectProperty(None)


class GranitNovakApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Manager()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GranitNovakApp().run()
```

KV file:

```
<CustLabel@Label>
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1

<MatLabel@CustLabel>:
    text_size: self.size
    padding: (10, 0)
    halign: "left"
    valign: "middle"

<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager

    screen_one: screen_one
    screen_two: screen_two

    ScreenOne:
        id: screen_one
        name: "Pretraga"
        manager: screen_manager

    ScreenTwo:
        id: screen_two
        name: "Tabela"
        manager: screen_manager

<ScreenOne>:
    GridLayout:
        id: search
        rows: 11
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10

        BoxLayout:
            CustLabel:
                text: "GRANIT NOVAK"
                bold: True
                italic: True
                font_size: 54

        BoxLayout:
            CustLabel:
                text: "Kod: "
                size_hint: .33, 1

            TextInput:
                id: kod_entry
                size_hint: .66, 1
                multiline: False

        BoxLayout:
            CustLabel:
                text: "Materijal: "
                size_hint: .33, 1

            TextInput:
                id: mat_entry
                size_hint: .66, 1
                multiline: False

        BoxLayout:
            CustLabel:
                text: "Pozicija: "
                size_hint: .33, 1

            TextInput:
                id: poz_entry
                size_hint: .66, 1
                multiline: False

        BoxLayout:
            CustLabel:
                text: " "

            CustLabel:
                text: "od"

            CustLabel:
                text: "do"

        BoxLayout:
            CustLabel:
                text: "Duzina:"
            TextInput:
                id: duz_od
                multiline: False
            TextInput:
                id: duz_do
                multiline: False

        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: " "

            CustLabel:
                text: "od"

            CustLabel:
                text: "do"

        BoxLayout:
            CustLabel:
                text: "Visina:"
            TextInput:
                id: vis_od
                multiline: False
            TextInput:
                id: vis_do
                multiline: False

        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: " "

            CustLabel:
                text: "od"

            CustLabel:
                text: "do"

        BoxLayout:
            CustLabel:
                text: "Debljina:"
            TextInput:
                id: deb_od
                multiline: False
            TextInput:
                id: deb_do
                multiline: False

        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: "POTVRDI"
                on_release:
                    root.konekcija(kod_entry.text, mat_entry.text, duz_od.text, duz_do.text,
                    vis_od.text, vis_do.text, deb_od.text, deb_do.text, poz_entry.text)
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                    root.manager.transition.duration = .2

<Row@BoxLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.86, 0.84, 0.76, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    value: ''
    MatLabel:
        text: root.value

<ScreenTwo>:
    rv: rv
    orientation: 'vertical'

    GridLayout:
        id: display
        rows: 3
        spacing: 5
        padding: 5
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: .1
            bgcolor: 0.86, 0.84, 0.76, 1
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: self.bgcolor
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            CustLabel:
                text: "Rezultati pretrage:"
                font_size: 40

        RecycleView:
            id: rv
            scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
            scroll_wheel_distance: dp(114)
            bar_width: dp(10)
            viewclass: 'Row'
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                default_size: None, dp(100)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
                spacing: dp(2)


        GridLayout:
            id: dug
            cols: 2
            size_hint_y: .1
            spacing: 5
            padding: 2

            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: .1
                Button:
                    text: "Prikaz"
                    focus: True
                    on_release:
                        root.populate()

            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: .1
                Button:
                    text: "NAZAD"
                    on_release:
                        root.clear()
                        root.change_screen()
                        root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                        root.manager.transition.duration = .2
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi and welcome! It makes me happy that you've looked for solutions and waited a while before posting. One thing tho, consider that Android doesn't have a MySQL server installed locally, there's no real reason for you to have a MySQL library on your phone. Usually, how dev's solve this is by sending WebSocket/REST/web-calls to a server with the data they want to store, and the server taking the request does the MySQL storage of things. If that makes sense? Even a simple HTTP POST request would get you far in this case (just make sure you use HTTPS, please).

Comment: I added code and kv file. I did not mention that I have already created a tkinter application that uses a database. With the Kivy application, I want to connect to the same database. So I could have access to the same data.